# What is an intuitive explantion for the fact that the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of energies is independent of mass?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

If you take the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of velocities (which depends on the mass) and substitute $v=\sqrt{\frac{2E}{m}}$ you get the distribution for the energies, which turns out to be independent of mass. What physical reality does this reflect? Why is the velocity distribution mass dependent, whereas the energy distribution is independent?

Comment: Since E is itself largely kinetic energy which *is* a function of mass, I don't think it's really accurate to say the energy distribution is "independent of mass", the mass dependence is just implicit.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to think about this is that, when considering the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution of velocities, the sole energy scale in the system (as is mostly the case when considering thermal equilibrium systems) is set by the temperature as $k_BT$. So the probabilities ($p(E)\mathrm{d}E$) being dimensionless can only be a function of a scaled energy ($E/k_BT$) and hence obviating the occurrence of any mass term in the expression (as the particle mass only sets a momentum scale and not an energy scale in the system).